# C++ 2d array search error

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, intellisense, strcmp

I'm trying to search a 2d array for a string.

The 2d array contains names and birthdays.

I want to search a name and display their birthday.

When I try to use strcmp to see if the inputted name compares to any in the array I get this error:

```
    IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists
```

Here is the bit of code I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char name[100];

string firstnames[2][4]= { {"John", "Emily", "Juan", "Sally"},
{"Nov 6", "Jan 13", "Oct 10", "Mar 29"} };

cout << "Enter a name: \n";
cin >> name; 

if (strcmp(name, firstnames[0][0]) == 0)
{

}
}
```

I don't understand how to fix this error? I had another similar error, but it went away when I changed the name to a char array instead of a string. So, I think it has something to do with that, but I don't know what to do to compare the inputted name to the array to find a match.

Comment: I get there is a problem there, but I don't know how to make the two work? the array of names needs to be string I think, and I've seen on multiple sites to compare it needs to be arrays of chars...Apparently, there is something I've missed and am not picking up on it.

Comment: I've not used std:: things much, where do I include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the string class, why not just make `name` a string object

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string name;

string courses[2][4]= { {"John", "Emily", "Juan", "Sally"},
{"Nov 6", "Jan 13", "Oct 10", "Mar 29"} };

cout << "Enter a course name: \n";
cin >> name; 

if (name == courses[0][0])
{
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: That worked! My book apparently really contradicted itself there...lol...  Thanks so much!

Comment: I actually agree with your answer more.  I posted mine to make the original code work, but I find that your solution is actually more geared towards proper C++ programming.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` function takes 2 parameters of type `const char*`. While `const char*` is implicitly convertible to `std::string`, it is not the other way around.

You can get a pointer to internal `char` array by `c_str` member function:

```
strcmp(name, firstnames[0][0].c_str());
```

or you can make a `string` from `name` and use `operator==`

```
if (std::string(name) == firstnames[0][0]) // ...
```

By the way, this:

```
char name[100];
cin >> name;
```

is pretty vulnerable to buffer overflows. What if the user enters more than 100 characters?
I'd suggest you use `std::string` from the start.

Comment: Ok! I now understand what my book meant, I guess. It never referred to c_str(), but this totally worked. Lol. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined your courses as type "string" but are accessing them like a "char*" (or in your case "char[]" which is pretty much the same thing).  All you would need to do is change this line:

```
if (strcmp(name, courses[0][0]) == 0)
```

to this:

```
if (strcmp(name, courses[0][0].c_str()) == 0)
```

Note the "c_str()".  This simply returns a char* pointer of your string which can be used in strcmp().

**As an aside**: is there any particular reason you have gone from using std::string to char*?  The reason I ask is because char* is more of a C-style way to program.  The std:string type was designed for C++ and contains built in comparison operators for other strings (and I believe even char*s).  Generally when programming in C++, it's best to use C++ style types whenever possible as there are a lot of advantages (RAII memory managements, standard algorithms, utility methods, etc...).